# How to pass row of dataframe into API if System.ArgumentException being raised?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, iterator, api-design

I Have df that looks like this:

```
id
1
2
3
```

I need to iterate through the dataframe (only 1 column in the frame df)and pass each ID into an API, where it says `&leadId=` after the equal sign. I.e `&leadId=1`

I have been trying this code:

```
lst = []

for index,row in df.iterrows():
    url = 'https://url.com/path/to?username=string&password=string&leadId=index'
    xml_data1 = requests.get(url).text
    lst.append(xml_data1)
    print(xml_data1)
```

but I get error:

```
System.ArgumentException: Cannot convert index to System.Int32.
```

What am I doing wrong in my code to not pass the index value into the parameter in the api? I have also tried passing row into the API and get the same error.

Thank you in advance.

edit:

converted dataframe to int by this line of code:

```
df = df.astype(int)
```

changed following to row instead of index in API parameters.

```
 for index,row in df.iterrows():
        url = 'https://url.com/path/to?username=string&password=string&leadId=row'
        xml_data1 = requests.get(url).text
        lst.append(xml_data1)
        print(xml_data1)
```

getting same error.

edit2:

full traceback:

```
System.ArgumentException: Cannot convert index to System.Int32.
Parameter name: type ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ScalarFormatter.FromString(String value, Type type)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ScalarFormatter.FromString(String value, Type type)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ValueCollectionParameterReader.Read(NameValueCollection collection)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()
```

Comment: I just checked type by doing `type(df.Id)`. I get ` pandas.core.series.Series`

Comment: I did print(type(row)) I get <class 'str'>

Comment: changed column to int, and changed index to row in URL still getting same error

Comment: Made an edit with how converted to int.

Comment: added full traceback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert your int to the type which the API expects

```
df.id=df.id.astype('int32')
```

With your current url string API is trying to convert 'row' which is a string to an integer which is not possible.

update your url string

```
url = 'https://url.com/path/to?username=string&password=string&leadId={}'.format(row)
```

Comment: I ran your line and succesfully converted the column to int32. However when I run the above code for the iteration still getting the same error

Comment: to add when I do print(type(row)) I see int32

Comment: `for index,row in df.iterrows():
        url = 'https://url.com/path/to?username=string&password=string&leadId=row'
        xml_data1 = requests.get(url).text
        lst.append(xml_data1)
        print(xml_data1)`

Comment: I am making a previous api calls to get the IDs which populate the current df. The populated df is the one I need to pass into the API to get more infromation. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: converted column back to string. No luck

Comment: url = 'https://url.com/path/to?username=string&password=string&leadId={}'.format(row) You were actually not passing anything. How did I miss that

Comment: Still getting the same error. I will work on the issue today and update. Thank you for the help

Comment: I got the issue fixed using your url fix. If you want to edit your answer I can approve it.